# Fragment over another fragment that can be closed swiping up

Tags: android, touch, fragment, swipe

I've made fragment A fullscreen that overlay another fragment B. I want to handle the swipe touch that can close the fragment A swiping up and reopen it swiping down.

I've made this example image:
[image]

How can I implement that? I've not found any tutorial of this particular case. Thank you.

Comment: If you modify [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures) to up-and-down you can use the FragmentManager to transact the wanted fragment.

Comment: ty for reply, now i try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several research, I've found a library that make implementation of sliding panels very easy.

It's the **Umano Android Panel**

[Umano Android Panel repository](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Answer (score 0):

`compile 'me.imid.swipebacklayout.lib:library:1.0.0'`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.darwich.swipetoclose.MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/id_radioGroup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/mode_left"
            android:text="Left"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/mode_right"
            android:text="Right"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/mode_bottom"
            android:text="Bottom"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/all"
            android:text="All"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends SwipeBackActivity {

    private SwipeBackLayout swipeBackLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RadioGroup trackingModeGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.id_radioGroup);
        swipeBackLayout = getSwipeBackLayout();

        trackingModeGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int edgeFlag;
                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.mode_left:
                        edgeFlag = SwipeBackLayout.EDGE_LEFT;
                        break;
                    case R.id.mode_right:
                        edgeFlag = SwipeBackLayout.EDGE_RIGHT;
                        break;
                    case R.id.mode_bottom:
                        edgeFlag = SwipeBackLayout.EDGE_BOTTOM;
                        break;
                    default:
                        edgeFlag = SwipeBackLayout.EDGE_ALL;
                }
                swipeBackLayout.setEdgeTrackingEnabled(edgeFlag);
            }
        });
    }
}
```